# Still vulnerable after patch installed

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

We have installed patches to out Magento sites (v1.9, patches 1533 5994 and 6285 (both versions)). 
However, despite installation reported successful, and after taking note of steps in 
[Applied Patches but still getting a vulnerable message?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64930/applied-patches-but-still-getting-a-vulnerable-message)
We are still being told by http://magento.com/security-patch that the site is vulnerable. Checking on https://templates-master.com/supeechecker lists the 3 patches we have applied as those missing. 
Is there any other steps that are required, but not mentioned in the post mentioned above?

Answer (score 5):

You missed the one patch that addresses the "Shoplift" exploit **SUPEE-5345** And this is the only one that the *byte shoplift tester* on magento.com tests for.

I don't know how reliable the templates-master tool is, but to be absolutely sure that the patches have been installed, please refer to: [How to check if Magento patch has been installed?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69012/how-to-check-if-magento-patch-has-been-installed)

#### Update:

Please check if you have copies in `app/code/local` of any of the files listed in `etc/applied.patches.list` which would render the patch useless. Class rewrites could also be a problem, if they copy lots of code from the original class.

#### See also:

- [How do I get a list of all class rewrites?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/1594/243)
- A tool to find overrides in `app/code/local`: https://github.com/aoepeople/mpmd

Comment: Thanks for your input, however I have now installed 5345 (as 5344 for v1.9), cleared cache, restarted apache, checked applied.patches.list, and all appears good, but tools are still reporting vulnerabilities??

Comment: See update for another possible reason

Comment: Still no good sadly. Could not get the rewrites list to work.
No files in app/code/local that match applied patch list either.