# Error while installing SUPEE-8788 patch in magento 1.7.0.2 version?

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, supee-8788

I am trying to install SUPEE-8788 patch in magento 1.7 but got below errors.

```
    Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Compare.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Cart.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Hunk #8 succeeded at 278 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 296 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #10 succeeded at 423 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #11 succeeded at 492 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #12 succeeded at 530 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #13 succeeded at 562 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #14 succeeded at 577 (offset 6 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/Transaction.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Controller/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 47 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/form.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/reorder/sidebar.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tag/customer/view.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml
can't find file to patch at input line 6299
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/checkout/cart.phtml app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|index 567c88f..2bcf244 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/checkout/cart.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 6311
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/customer/form/login.phtml app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/customer/form/login.phtml
|index a6d2ac1..7d61c3b 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/customer/form/login.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/customer/form/login.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 6323
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
|index 5decee9..871f998 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 6335
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/wishlist/view.phtml app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/wishlist/view.phtml
|index f2a27fd..550e860 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/wishlist/view.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/wishlist/view.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
checking file downloader/Maged/View.php
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
checking file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
checking file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
checking file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
checking file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
checking file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
checking file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
checking file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
```

I have also done these things before installing this patch.

1) Revert SUPEE-8788 v1 (Not installed in my case)

2) Revert SUPEE-1533 (Not installed in my case)

3) Install SUPEE-3941

How can I overcome this problem please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems)

Answer (score 3):

**Try this,Hope it's help for you.**

> Before applying security patch 8788, make sure to apply all previous patches.
>
> ```
> SUPEE-3941
>
> SUPEE-7405
>
> SUPEE-6788
>
> SUPEE-6285 
>
> SUPEE-5994 
>
> SUPEE-5344
> ```
>
> You can scan your store https://www.magereport.com
>
> For more help visit following:-
>
> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/150220/18639
> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160779/18639

Comment: Helo @Randhir could you please tell where you find that these patches have to be installed before installing 8788 patch.

Comment: As far as I know I think we have to    Revert 8788 v1 (if installed), Revert 1533 (if installed), install 3941 after that we can install 8788

Comment: @ Ramkishan You can download all security patches on this link :- https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download1972

Comment: @Ramkishan You can also install all previous without ssh on this link :- https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-8788-without-ssh/

Comment: You are not getting my point @Randhir I am asking where you find above information

Comment: @Ramkishan I already faced same issue. you just apply all previous patches.after you install 8788

Answer (score 2):

The patch tells you that it cannot find files in

> app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template

The `default/iphone` theme was part of Magento 1.7 and the patch also contains security fixes for this theme. You probably removed the theme and this makes the patch fail.

#### Solution:

- Download Magento 1.7.0.2 and copy `app/design/default/iphone` into your installation.
- Apply the patch
- Remove the iphone theme again (or just leave it there)

Comment: yes you are right @Fabian. I did exactly same before you have given answer. thank you for your answer